# Embed Tag for Audio Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, html, audio, embed

I added this tag to a web page a few months ago:

```
<embed src="beep.wav" autostart="false" width="1" height="1" id="audio" enablejavascript="true">
```

And I have some javascript to play the sound:

```
function playbeep()
{
    var sound = document.getElementById( "audio" );
    sound.Play();
}
```

This worked perfectly when I implemented it. Of course, the user had to install quicktime, but for the userbase, that was acceptable.

Keep in mind, I haven't messed with any of this code in a long time, and I find that it no longer works in Firefox or Chrome. Only in Internet Explorer.

If I try it in the first two browsers, I get these errors:

Firefox 26 and 27:

```
TypeError: sound.Play is not a function
```

Chrome 32.0.1700.107:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'Play'
```

It works in IE 11.0.9600.16428. I can't figure out what happened to cause this. Is there an alternative to the method I'm using for playing the audio? HTML5 is not an option, so I can't use anything that requires that.
I did take a look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLEmbedElement
and it shows no Play function, so I don't suppose the error is false. But, if they took that out, I don't see how I'm suppose to play the audio now.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why is HTML5 not an option?  If you're targeting IE 11, Firefox 26/27 and Chrome 32, HTML5 is certainly not an issue for the user agent....

Comment: Well, I guess it is possible. Though, I don't no what the implications will be. The application that this is part of is over 10 years old. As you can imagine, a lot of the code is outdated or even deprecated. I'm not sure what kind of compatibility issues there may be by adding HTML5 stuff.

Comment: I think you're pretty safe using HTML5 stuff...even if your document isn't specified with the HTML5 `<!doctype>`.  See this article: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-the-html5-audio-property.  It includes information about fallbacks for older browsers.